# Need to reproduce a specific HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have to reproduce this image http://www.sahmreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/FoxMind-Kulami-Board-Setup.jpg as an HTML table where all the td have the attributes colspan and rowspan set, but because of an empty row and the other the table is compacted, is there a way to fix it?
If I add another row and another column it works as in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsylR.jpg but I should hide the row and the column.
Do you know if there is a way to fix this?

The table & css is as follows:

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by “compacted”?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `&nbsp;` to the ones that collapse?

Comment: Add min-width and min-height to your td in css

Comment: @Grumpy it doesn't work anyway

Comment: @Dai if you run the code you see that the table is much smaller than expected

Comment: @rawnewdlz it doesn't work with `&nbsp;` either

Comment: @Smeterix When I click the "run code snippet" button the table looks fine to me. Can you post an image comparison showing what you expect to see vs. what you actually see?

Comment: Can you please edit your question? I don't understand what this part means:
"but because of an empty row and the other the table is compacted, is there a way to fix it?"

Comment: Problem is if the all have same colspan, they will be same width. You be better off with each cell being a dot and setting borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the rows span the same, it will collapse. You are probably better off building it cell by cell and setting the borders. I was waiting for a build to run so I made the table quickly.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #f5e7d1;
}

td {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

td.br {
  border-right: 1px solid #888;
}

td.bb {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}

td > label > input { display : none; }
td > label > span { 
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(197,199,163,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
td > label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
td > label > input:checked + span {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,100,102,1) 100%);
  border-color: #F09;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox" checked><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="bb"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="br"><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class=""><label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```